# Diagrams/Explanations of Django request processing?

Tags: django

Is there a detailed diagram that describes how Django processes requests, from when the request is first handed to it until it hands back a response, specifically including how database connections are related to requests, e.g., 1 to 1, 1 to N, etc.?

If not, I'd appreciate a pointer to the point in the code where Django starts processing the request.

Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think this article includes the information you're looking for with a decent (if cluttered) diagram: http://uswaretech.com/blog/2009/06/django-request-response-processing/

You can also use the [django-debug-toolbar](http://github.com/robhudson/django-debug-toolbar) to get more info about the SQL (and lots of other stuff) happening on behind the scenes of a particular request.

Comment: Thanks. The blog had exactly the details I needed (where in the Django source it delegated to the handlers, etc.)

Answer (score 11):

There is this diagram from [The Django Book](http://www.djangobook.com/en/2.0) (online version):
[image]

A breakdown of this process is described in Chapter 3 under the heading [How Django Processes a Request: Complete Details](http://www.djangobook.com/en/2.0/chapter03/).

Answer (score 0):

Most of links are not working mentioned in above answers, I got one following link which is also an great reading to understand the request processing by django:

http://www.b-list.org/weblog/2006/jun/13/how-django-processes-request/